# IIS (Azure) Redirect Non-www to www and SSL - Problem at Non-Root Url

Tags: azure, redirect, iis

I'm trying on an Azure Web App Service to redirect my website requests to following

*Rules:*

1. Non https requests should be redirected to one with https
2. Non www requests to be redirected to one with www

*Desired Redirects:*

**Requested Url -> Redirected To**

```
 1. http<nolink>://example.com -> https<nolink>://www.example.com/
 2. http<nolink>://www.example.com ->
    https<nolink>://www.example.com/
 3. https<nolink>://example.com ->
    https<nolink>://www.example.com/
 4. https<nolink>://www.example.com
    -> https<nolink>://www.example.com/
```

I enabled the HTTPS ONLY checkbox at the dashboard and it works for the first rule.

Rewrite configuration:

```
  <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
```

Works for the second rule (at Root-Urls)

but I have the problem with the following non-root url...

*Problem to Redirects:*

**Requested Url -> Redirected To (NOW and is a Problem)**

```
 1. http<nolink>://example.com/login -> https<nolink>://example.com/login
 2. https<nolink>://example.com/login -> https<nolink>://example.com/login
```

these redirects are NOT redirected to WWW but they should have WWW and SSL. All assets(css,js,...), on the other hand, are correctly redirected. (via WWW and SSL)

Does anyone know this problem or does anyone have an idea what this can be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: this rule works for root urls and assests but if i enter a url with subdirectory ... like http://example.com/login it redirects to http://example.com/login (it does not redirect ... )

Comment: Did you clear the cache and try again?

Comment: yes ... cache is not the problem

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see detailed information.